# In MongoDB, are causally consistent sessions subject to reading data that may be rolled back?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I'm using a causally consistent session in MongoDB, I can execute an acknowledged write that gets acknowledged before the write is written to a majority.  Because I get acknowledgement so quickly, I can then do a read and see the results of my write.  However, since I haven't waited for 'majority' acknowledgement, is it possible that my write could be rolled back, but I wouldn't know it because the 'read' that I did didn't depend on the majority members of the cluster actually getting the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can execute an acknowledged write that gets acknowledged before the write is written to a majority is it possible that my write could be rolled back

If you are *not* specifying [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#write-concern) `majority`, then yes it is possible that your write could be rolled back. However if you are, then the writes are *unacknowledged*, MongoDB does not return the operation time and the cluster time for unacknowledged write operations. Unacknowledged writes do not imply any causal relationship.

In addition, if you specify [retryable writes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/) true, the client will attempt one retry. This helps address transient network errors and replica set elections, but not persistent network errors.

> the 'read' that I did didn't depend on the majority members of the cluster actually getting the data?

Within a [Causally Consistent](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#causal-consistency) session, the read operation would wait to see the cluster time after the write operation.

See more information on [Implementation of Cluster Write Causal Consistency in MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/implementation-of-cluster-wide-causal-consistency-in-mongodb)